# JWT not working on live server with Vuejs, Laravel

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jwt, vue-component, vue-router

I am working on a SPA, I have used JWT authentication for a login system. on the local server its working fine, I mean when I click login I get the token etc and store on local storage and it redirects me to dashboard everything perfect.

[image]
[image]

but on a live server, I get the token but it doesn't store it on local storage.
I am completely lost. I tried everything but still. please help me with this.
it's my first time with the SPA so I am not sure what I am missing.

**Login Method**

```
login(){
  User.login(this.form)
}
```

User.js

```
import Token from './Token'
import AppStorage from './AppStorage'

class User {
    login(data) {
        axios.post('/api/auth/login', data)
            .then(res => this.responseAfterLogin(res))
            .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data))
    }

    responseAfterLogin(res) {
        const access_token = res.data.access_token
        const username = res.data.user
        if (Token.isValid(access_token)) {
            AppStorage.store(username, access_token)
            window.location = '/me/dashboard'
        }
    }

    hasToken() {
        const storedToken = AppStorage.getToken();
        if (storedToken) {
            return Token.isValid(storedToken) ? true : this.logout()
        }
        return false
    }

    loggedIn() {
        return this.hasToken()
    }

    logout() {
        AppStorage.clear()
        window.location = '/me/login'
    }

    name() {
        if (this.loggedIn()) {
            return AppStorage.getUser()
        }
    }

    id() {
        if (this.loggedIn()) {
            const payload = Token.payload(AppStorage.getToken())
            return payload.sub
        }
    }

    own(id) {
        return this.id() == id
    }

    admin() {
        return this.id() == 1
    }

}

export default User = new User();
```

**Token.js**

```
class Token {


    isValid(token){
        const payload = this.payload(token);
        if(payload){
            return payload.iss == "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login" ? true : false
        }

        return false
    }

    payload(token){
        const payload = token.split('.')[1]
        return this.decode(payload)
    }

    decode(payload){
        return JSON.parse(atob(payload))

    }



}

export default Token = new Token();
```

**AppStorage.js**

```
class AppStorage {    

    storeToken (token) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    }

    storeUser (user) {
        localStorage.setItem('user', user);
    }

    store (user, token) {
        this.storeToken(token)
        this.storeUser(user)
    }

    clear () {
        localStorage.removeItem('token')
        localStorage.removeItem('user')
    }

    getToken () {
        return localStorage.getItem('token')
    }

    getUser () {
        return localStorage.getItem('user')
    }

}


export default AppStorage = new AppStorage()
```

Thanks

Comment: Does your dev version still work if you clear localStorage? I also notice that you are using `localStorage` without the `window` prefix. Could it be that you are compiling it to code with "use strict"? Try adding a `debugger` statement to find this code in your compiled production code and figure out what it is compiling to. That should give you a clue what is going wrong here.

Comment: Is your live server also "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login" ? If not, then you likely need to update your Token->isValid method to match the domain the live server is on.

Comment: @Freddy I am facing kind of similar problem- Would you help me please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57991720/deploy-laravelvuejs-application